# Convert Den into Bedroom

Tags: bedroom, remodeling

I'm looking at a house that has a room that is listed as a **den**. It looks like a bedroom without a door or closet. It does have a regular sized window for a bedroom.

What would I have to do in order to change in into a bedroom so that it could be listed as having another bedroom? Would adding the door and closet require permits?

This was an option on the house to have either a bedroom or den so I don't think there would be any issues with the number of occupants or bathrooms.

The home is in California.

Comment: Listings aren't required to match the title exactly. I bought a house listed as 1100 sqft, but the title only lists it as 800 sqft since the office is above the garage and not included. The title means almost nothing. The title might come in if the people buying the house are really fighting with the bank on the valuation of the house, but I wouldn't sweat it.